# Don't redirect to http://stackexchange.com/site-not-found?host=

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 500-server-error, stackexchange.com, redirection

if it was just a typo it gets really annoying to correct

Comment: Sorry, what steps do you take to produce this behaviour?

Comment: @Jon: Try going to, for example, http://wobapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see now. Hmmm... I can see why this page exists, but I'm unsure if removing it is a good solution. (Thanks @Nicholas)

Comment: @Jon Seigel: not removing the error site itself, only remove the current behaviour of changing the browsers URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good point. This has been implemented.

Comment: +1 for making the real answer and the joke answer the same answer

Comment: @Popular I was having trouble figuring out what my (unintended) joke was until I realize that Jon edited it away!

Comment: Aw, I thought it was intentional. Oh well, it's still an upvote-worthy answer.